# /dev/null doesn't seem to work on travis CI

Tags: python, travis-ci

I am running some automated test in Travis CI and I am having trouble in running two parrelel comands so basically before testing we should run main flask app by executing `python app/main.py` and after that we should run `nosetests /app/tests/test.py`. To run this i am using `start_server.sh` which contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python app/main.py > /dev/null &
nosetests app/tests/test.py --with-coverage
```

and this is my travis config:

```
language: python3
sudo: required
addons:
apt:
    packages:
    - python-dev
python:
- '3.5'

before_install:
- sudo apt-get -qq update
- sudo apt-get -y install librsvg2-bin
- sudo apt-get -y install pdftk 
- sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
- sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv

install:
- virtualenv  -p python3 flask_env
- source flask_env/bin/activate
- pip3 install -r requirements/test.txt
- pip3 install -r requirements/dev.txt

before_script:
- chmod +x ./start_server.sh

script:
- sh start_server.sh
- python -m pyflakes .

deploy:
- provider: releases
skip_cleanup: true
api_key:
    secure: "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"
file: "all-badges.pdf"
on:
    branch: master

after_success:
- deactivate
- 'bash <(curl -s https://codecov.io/bash)'
```

Travis log: https://travis-ci.org/fossasia/badgeyay/builds/285063294?utm_source=github_status&utm_medium=notification
Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: There is no `language: python3`, so you'd be running on the Ruby image (which should be identical to one with `language: python` at the moment, but this is not guaranteed).

Comment: @banzaiman it's not an issue..please see travis log

Comment: I didn't say it was.

Comment: @banzaiman Do you have any solution?

Comment: It looks to me that the command that does not return is [`nosetests app/tests/test.py --with-coverage`](https://github.com/fossasia/badgeyay/blob/54fcfadeeeb5e2a589a7ba18d5ff5a791f59913a/start_server.sh#L3), not `python app/main.py > /dev/null &`. I don't know enough Python to tell you why that is.

Comment: You probably want to include the server/app startup in your nose fixtures. Otherwise you can only ever test up to the first failure and the test setup would also be much more replicable.

Comment: @renemilk Can you please gimme resources or tell me how to do that..i am new to travis

Comment: That's entirely unrelated to travis. You should be able to be find lots of material on testing flask (or similar python web server apps), with nose (or pytest) with google.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try running `sh start_server.sh` in the background?

Think this should do the trick:

```
script:
- "sh start_server.sh &"
```

Alternatively, you might want to play with commands like `setsid`, redirection of stdin, stdout and stderr, and/or disable `sh`s job control in `start_server.sh`.

Comment: I will give it a try